# Timeit with range of int as parameter for function

Tags: python, timeit

I want to compare execution times of functions with timeit with a range of (0,30) as parameters, so I can store the exection time of each call with a different parameter in a list.
This repeat function calls (as per default) the function 5 times, instead of returning the times for all parameters 0 to 30

```
times = timeit.repeat("for x in range(30): foo(x)", "from __main__ import foo",
                      number=100)
```

So how can I pass the parameters to the function and get the execution time for each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
from time import sleep
from timeit import timeit


def foo(x):
    sleep(1/(x+1))


n = 1
print(list([timeit(lambda: foo(x), number=n) / n] for x in range(30)))
```

Result:

```
[[1.0116304], [0.5029303], [0.34732699999999994], [0.2513573], etc.]
```

It runs `timeit` for `foo(0)`, then `foo(1)`, etc. It runs it `n` times (you could set it to a 100) and it divides the outcome by `n` to obtain the time taken by each run on average.

The `list()` is there because it will just print the generator object in there otherwise - square brackets would also work.

I think the `lambda:`  is the part you were after. It allows you to pass in the parameter you want to pass in without having to change how `timeit` is called, as `timeit` expects a function to call to be passed in, so you can't pass in `foo(x)` (since that would just evaluate to `None`, the function result).